Android: How to stop intent-based Bluetooth scanning?
I've been struggling with this issue for a long time and have searched through many articles, but still haven't found a solution. Could you please provide me with some direction?
I'm using intent-based Bluetooth scanning to continuously operate in the background, and the experimental results have been very good (I can correctly receive the Bluetooth list in the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver, and it can run for a long time).
However! When I try to stop the scan using stopScan, at first I thought it stopped normally, but after a while, without opening the application, I receive scan results again.
What exactly happened? Why is it that even though stopScan was called, results are still being received?
For the Bluetooth part, I used both the native SDK and the Android-Scanner-Compat-Library, and encountered the same situation. Therefore, I believe it's an issue with the native SDK.
Here's the code I wrote using the Android-Scanner-Compat-Library.
I'm not sure if the provided information is sufficient to identify the issue.
If there's any additional content you need from me, please let me know.
    <receiver
        android:name=".BluetoothReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    private fun startBluetoothLeScanIntent() {

        val filters = ArrayList<ScanFilter>()

        val filter = ScanFilter.Builder()
             .setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid(UUID.fromString(UUID_STRING)))
             .build()
        
        filters.add(filter)

        val settings = ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
            .build()

        val intent = Intent(requireContext(), BluetoothReceiver::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("test", "")
        
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(requireContext(), 0, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_MUTABLE)

        BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner().startScan(
            filters,
            settings,
            requireContext(),
            pendingIntent,
            0
        )
    }

    private fun stopBluetoothLeScanIntent() {
        BluetoothLeScannerCompat.getScanner().stopScan(requireContext(), pendingIntent, 0)
    }

class BluetoothReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    companion object {
        private val TAG = BluetoothReceiver::class.simpleName
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val hasBleExtra = intent.hasExtra(BluetoothLeScannerCompat.EXTRA_CALLBACK_TYPE)

        if (hasBleExtra) {
            val bleCallbackType =
                intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothLeScannerCompat.EXTRA_CALLBACK_TYPE, -1)

            if (bleCallbackType != -1) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}


btw, make sure you check for the action in onReceive (and  maybe some extras that you pass). this helps make sure your application doesn't respond to unnecessary triggers.

@Vishnu Thank you for your suggestion. It is necessary!

Looks like a bug of the library. Try unregistering your broadcast receiver like unregisterReceiver(BluetoothReceiver);

Thank you for your response! I've tried using it, but I'm getting errors like 'Not registered, unable to unregister'. The onReceive still triggers, and it only responds with an empty array.
